# Скрытие столбцов, в которых нет данных

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Возможно ли через скрипты скрывать столбцы, в которых нет данных?

Answer (score 0):

С помощью Google Apps Script возможно скрывать колонки. Например, [hideColumn(column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumncolumn) скрывает колонки переданного диапазона

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// This hides the first column
var range = sheet.getRange("A1");
sheet.hideColumn(range);
```

Осталось только посчитать, какие именно колонки скрывать.

Лучший способ для этого - использование Sheets API.

Пример на Google Apps Script

```
/**
 * Hides empty columns on a sheet
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Spreadsheet.Sheet} sheet
 * @param {number} [headersRows=1] Perhaps the headlines should be skipped? If not, enter 0
 * @return {void}
 */
const hideEmptyColumnsOfSheet_ = (sheet, headersRows = 1) => {
  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  const bookId = sheet.getParent().getId();

  const values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(bookId, sheet.getName(), {
    majorDimension: 'COLUMNS',
  });

  const createUpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest = fabricUpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest_(
    sheetId
  );

  const updateDimensionPropertiesRequests = values.values.reduceRight((
    /** @type {Array.<GoogleAppsScript.Sheets.Schema.UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest>} */ p,
    /** @type {Array.<any>} */ c,
    /** @type {number} */ i
  ) => {
    if (!c.slice(headersRows).some(Boolean)) {
      let last = p[p.length - 1];
      if (last == undefined) {
        last = createUpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest({
          startIndex: i,
          endIndex: i + 1,
        });
        p.push(last);
      }
      if (i + 1 === last.range.startIndex) last.range.startIndex = i;
      else
        p.push(
          createUpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest({
            startIndex: i,
            endIndex: i + 1,
          })
        );
    }
    return p;
  }, []);

  const batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest = Sheets.newBatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
  batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.requests = updateDimensionPropertiesRequests.map(
    updateDimensionPropertiesRequest => {
      const request = Sheets.newRequest();
      request.updateDimensionProperties = updateDimensionPropertiesRequest;
      return request;
    }
  );
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(batchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest, bookId);
};
```

`fabricUpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest_` можно найти [в полном примере](https://github.com/contributorpw/google-apps-script-snippets/tree/master/snippets/sheets/hide_empty_columns).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]